# Show that $f = x^5 + 5x^3 + 1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

**My solution:** Because of Gauss Lemma, it is enough to show irreducibility over $\mathbb Z[x]$. The only possible integers roots are divisors of $1$, so $\pm 1$, but $f(1) \ne 0$ and $f(-1) \ne 0$, so $f$ is irreducible.

That's my solution. Now I looked in the official solution, which is more involved. So I wanted to ask if my solution has some faults?

For completeness, the **official solution**: Because of Gauss Lemma, it is enough to show irredubility in $\mathbb Z[x]$. We do it with reduction modulo 2, then $\overline{f} = x^5 + x^3 + 1 \in \mathbb Z_2[x]$. Is $\overline{f}$ irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$, so is $f$ irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. We have to show that no irreducible polynomial of degree $\le 2$ divides $\overline{f}$. Because $\overline{f}$ has no root in $\mathbb Z_2$, it has no linear factor. And the only irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Z_2$ is $x^2 + x + 1$. Polynomial division shows that this is no divisor of $\overline{f}$. It is $\overline{f} = (x^3 + x^2 + x)(x^2 + x + 1) + x + 1$.

Comment: You checked if it didn't have any rational roots, not whether it was irreducible over the rationals. The former only implies the latter when the degree is $\le3$ (can you ascertain why?).

Comment: There are other ways to see this, for example that $f(x+4)$ satisfies Eisenstein's criterion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ may have no rational roots, but that does only mean that it has no linear factors (i.e. degree $1$) in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. You forgot to test for factorizations into higher-degree polynomials. One of those would need to have degree not greater than $2$, and that is what the official proof checked.

Comment: $x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + x\sqrt{2} + 1)(x^2 - x\sqrt{2} + 1)$.

Comment: Better example might be: $x^4+4 = (x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$

Comment: @ncmathsadist Reducibility over $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ might be two different beasts.